# Need help to decide about enum implementation for SQL Server in connection with C#

Tags: sql-server, enums, lookup-tables

I'm looking for some more insight to implement enums with SQL Server. SQL Server has no direct enum support and C# does not have string enums. For SQL Server the main options are Check constraints and lookup tables. For enums that don't change (e.g. On, Off) Check constraints work. For enums that will have new members added (e.g. category, type) lookup tables don't require changes in the database definition. New values can be easily added to the lookup table. Lookup table data can also serve to fill comboboxes in the frontend. Additionally lookup tables can hold sort orders if needed.

Most recommendations advocate a tinyint field as the primary and foreign key for efficiency and easy mapping to C# enums. The major drawback is that without joining each enum to its lookup table the records are not human readable. I favor natural keys if possible. They are easier to read and understand and less error-prone. Our database holds a lot of tables with many enums. Therefore I don't feel comfortable using a lot of integer keys for enums, since 1,2,3,... will always have a different meaning.

I see two solutions:

1. Use a char(1) field as the key. The character code can be used in C# as the enum value. The problem is that sometimes enum members might start with the same letter and a different non-intuitive letter has to be used which negates the readability. It still would be better than numbers.
2. Use a varchar field of appropriate length and enter the full value (e.g. AddressType: 'Home', 'Work', 'Shipping'). This will provide optimal readability. The lookup table still ensures integrity. In C# the enums integer values are just used internally. For database operations the enum name can be used.
   The drawback is increased space in the database. Considering the amount of other data the extra characters per record are neglectable. The join would cost more, but it is only needed for inserts or updates for integrity check. The lookup tables can still feed combobox values.

The main drawback with both solutions is that if changing an enum would require changing the key for readability all affected records need to be changed. Since enums usually don't change I don't see this as a practical problem. If enums essentially change due to an application update there is normally more to update anyway.

For our case I favor to give up easy update for readability. Is there anything I overlook when using char or varchar as a key? If not, is there anything else that makes option 1 or 2 the better choice?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use a natural key that is a readable varchar, but not going to change? I.e. `key: 'HOME', value: 'Home'`. Then you can rephrase the value of 'Home' and keep the key of 'HOME'.

Comment: How would you intend to deal with Flags enums where values can be combinations of enum bit values? e.g.: [SslProtocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols).

Comment: @GSerg: That was the idea.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: in the case of flags integers would be the obvious key. I'm not opposing integer as keys for enums in general. It always depends on the case. I was asking for the case of natural string enums.